# Renderscript error?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-renderscript

I am working on application which uses Renderscript Liberary. I am getting below error while build project

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.0/mipsel-linux-android-ld'
```

Also getting following warning.

```
Warning:Linking two modules of different target triples: /Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.0/renderscript/lib/bc/mips/libclcore.bc' is 'armv7--linux-android' whereas '/home/appaspect-ankita/Projects/Native Application/app/build/generated/res/rs/debug/raw/bc32/beziercurve.bc' is 'armv7-none-linux-gnueabi'
```

Here in warning it seems like different armv7 issue. But I don't know how to solve this error. 
I searched a lot but didn't find the right solution. 
Please help to resolve it. 
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/2519

Comment: have you using any any render script in your app?